# how to have one copy of ubuntu software center to all desktop environment?

Tags: gnome, software-center, desktop-environments

why does the ubuntu software center disappear when I change my ubuntu unity environment to gnome environment? I could use

```
sudo apt-get install software center
```

But it would just takes more memory to my hard disk since there is already ubuntu software center in on its default. How to have a one copy of ubuntu software center to all desktop environment?

Comment: If you are worried about the space it occupies, don't worry. none of linux software occupy any noticeable space

Comment: @MostafaAhagarha well that's not exactly accurate statement. There are many software examples that are gigantic. Software Center isn't that large but still making statement to claim that all Linux software is lean isn't accurate

Comment: How did you install other environment ? Also, unless you remove Unity, the software Center should still be there. You just need to call it from command line or just use its shortcut in /usr/share/applications

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I think it is included since I chose to install third party software in ubuntu installation. I have already call the software center in the command line but it returns nothing.